# Tensorflow: handling sparse input data

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm wondering what can be done if the input vector is sparse. That is, some of the samples have a valid value in the Nth position, for some, it is missing. Obviously I cannot just set that to 0, or any other value (I think), because the network would still process that. How could I disable parts of the network conditionally? E.g. I'd set the invalid field value to -1, and somehow detect that in the model, which would disable that subnet. Hm.. Multiply layer?

After some thinking, I came with up with something, but it's incomplete.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Lambda, Dense, Conv2D, Flatten
# 3 samples, historySize = 2, numFeatures=9
train_x = [
    [.5, .6, -1, .2, -1, .6, -1, .3, .3],
    [-1, .2, .5, .7, .2, .6, .4, -1, .9]
  ],[
    [.5, .6, .9, .2, .9, .6, .9, .3, .3],
    [.3, .2, .5, .7, .2, .6, .4, .7, .9]
  ],[
    [.5, .6, .5, .2, .4, .6, .0, .3, .3],
    [.2, .2, .5, .7, .2, .6, .4, .8, .9]
  ]

train_y = [
  [1,0],
  [1,0],
  [0,1]
]

inp = Input(shape=(2, 9))
msk = Lambda(lambda x: x + 1.)(inp)
msk = Lambda(lambda x: tf.clip_by_value(x, 0., 1.))(msk)

x = Lambda(lambda x: tf.stack(x, axis=3))([inp, msk])
x = Conv2D(2, (1,2), activation='relu')(x)
x = Flatten()(inp)
x = Dense(9)(x)
x = Dense(2)(x)

m = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=x)

m.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

m.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=2000)

print("Prediction for train_x[0]:")
print(m.predict([train_x[0]])[0])

print("Prediction for train_x[1]:")
print(m.predict([train_x[1]])[0])

print("Prediction for train_x[2]:")
print(m.predict([train_x[2]])[0])
```

The idea is to set missing values to -1, given the inputs are normalized to [0,1]. Then adding them 1 and clipping creates an input mask. The input mask together with the input should be processed together. Here I'm trying to apply a convolution that would detect the following cases:

```
MASK   FEATURE   OUTPUT
1       0         0
1       x         x
0       0         0
```

Nah... This is basically an AND gate, which is the same as setting missing values to zero. I guess then the network will reduce the MASK+FEATURE pair anyway, and it just won't trigger an activation?

Or what if all the inputs would be normalized into [0.1, 1] and the missing values set to 0. That way any (real)zero inputs would get normalized to be 0.1, still trigger some response, meaning that there IS input, which is zero, whereas 0 means actually non-existent input.

Comment: I think you should be a bit more specific. Are you talking about image image classification task or time series task?
Are you doing multi-class or multi-label classification?

Comment: Time series classification, multi-class

Comment: Your answer means that each of time-series belongs to one and only one class and there are some time-series that doesn't have class associated with it. So, why you don't just remove these samples from training?

Comment: A sample is an N-length long time series window with F number of features at each point in time (plus the class it belongs to 0 or 1). Some elements of some samples have some missing features, but there are classes associated to each. I cannot remove the whole sample if any feature is missing, because most samples have missing features, and these features are usually different from sample to sample.

Comment: I don't think that tensorflow provides any built-in solution for the problem. The main discussion leads to the following advices:
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/36047/fill-missing-values-and-normalise

Comment: And, perhaps, Masking layer can also contribute?

Comment: Masking layer skips timesteps, which means it skips the complete sample.